# Error in a "List Reversing" python program

Tags: python, list

everyone! 
I am a beginner in python programming. I am writing a python program to reverse a given input list. Following is the code for it:

```
    L1=list(input("Enter the numbers of list to be reversed : "))
    L2=[]

    def rever(La,Lb):
     if len(Lb)==0: 
      return La                               
     else:
      return rever(La.append(Lb.pop(0)),Lb)

    print rever(L2,L1)
```

For example, if we input,

```
    1,2,3
```

The output should be,

```
    [3,2,1]
```

But this is not happening. Python is giving the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Q3.py", line 10, in <module>
        print rever(L2,L1)
      File "Q3.py", line 8, in rever
        return rever(La.append(Lb.pop(0)),Lb)
      File "Q3.py", line 8, in rever
        return rever(La.append(Lb.pop(0)),Lb)
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I don't get it. Please help me out!!

Comment: you might want to check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation

Comment: You can do it easier using: list[::-1] . But your way is a good exercise to learn about recursion ^^

Answer (score 1):

may be you should look at this, instead of pop and append

```
In [5]: L1=list(input("Enter the numbers of list to be reversed : "))
Enter the numbers of list to be reversed : 1,2,3,4,5

In [6]: L1
Out[6]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [7]: L2 = L1[::-1]

In [8]: L2
Out[8]: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Or just use the reverse method `L1.reverse()` to reverse in-place. However, I suspect the OP is doing some kind of exercise.

Comment: yes it seems to be the exercise, hence i gave a slicing option rather than answering in pop and append, using python idioms is what OP should learn

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues.  First the working way:

```
def rever(La,Lb):
    if len(Lb)==0: 
        return La
    else:
        La.append(Lb.pop())
        return rever(La,Lb)
```

`list.append` appends in place, meaning it returns None.  Since you are passing `La.append` as an argument in the recursion, you get an error on the second iteration.

If you wanted to do it that way then you could do

```
return rever(La + [Lb.pop()], Lb)
```

The second issue is you are popping off the front and appending.  So you will get the same order.  Instead, pop off the end (no argument to pop) and append.

Answer (score 0):

The `append` method operates in-place, altering the original list and returning `None`, giving you the error. Try this instead:

```
def rever(La, Lb):
    if len(Lb) == 0:
        return La
    else:
        La.append(Lb.pop())
        return rever(La, Lb)
```

You could also refactor your code to something like this:

```
def rever(La, Lb):
    if Lb:
        La.append(Lb.pop())
        return rever(La, Lb)
    return La
```

This uses the facts that an empty list is `False` in a boolean context, and there can only be one return value for any function.

Comment: Just FYI, this still doesn't reverse as it is appending the `pop(0)` item each time instead of using `pop()`